# Why PHP-FPM 5.6 segfaults during mysqlnd calls?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, pdo, segmentation-fault

I have nginx 1.6, mysql 5.5, php 5.6.11 server configuration. Occasionally, PHP segfaults, always when it's been idle for a few minutes (no requests have been made). If there are requests, this segfault doesn't happen.

I have run core dump through `gdb` utility with this result:

```
root@server3:/# gdb /usr/local/php-5.6.11-fpm/sbin/php-fpm /tmp/coredump-php-fpm.5867
....
Reading symbols from /usr/local/php-5.6.11-fpm/sbin/php-fpm...done.
[New LWP 5867]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff1effe000
Core was generated by `php-fpm: p'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000035417f0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000035417f0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000009a9548 in php_mysqlnd_net_send_ex_pub (net=0x350e010, buffer=0x7fff1ef47e10 "\001", count=1, conn_stats=0x353ee30, error_info=0x35323b8)
    at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_net.c:442
#2  0x0000000000996420 in php_mysqlnd_cmd_write (_packet=0x34ca830, conn=0x3532280) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:999
#3  0x00000000009702f5 in php_mysqlnd_conn_data_simple_command_send_request_pub (conn=0x3532280, command=COM_PING, arg=0x0, arg_len=0, silent=1 '\001', 
    ignore_upsert_status=1 '\001') at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.c:356
#4  0x00000000009706c6 in php_mysqlnd_conn_data_simple_command_pub (conn=0x3532280, command=COM_PING, arg=0x0, arg_len=0, ok_packet=PROT_OK_PACKET, silent=1 '\001', 
    ignore_upsert_status=1 '\001') at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.c:381
#5  0x000000000097bb98 in php_mysqlnd_conn_data_ping_pub (conn=0x3532280) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.c:1728
#6  0x000000000077c378 in pdo_mysql_check_liveness (dbh=0x3532830) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c:493
#7  0x000000000076aa10 in zim_PDO_dbh_constructor (ht=4, return_value=0x34ccdd8, return_value_ptr=0x7f3796811b80, this_ptr=0x34f8708, return_value_used=0)
    at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/ext/pdo/pdo_dbh.c:307
#8  0x0000000000acb14b in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7f3796811eb8) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:558
#9  0x0000000000acb91b in ZEND_DO_FCALL_BY_NAME_SPEC_HANDLER (execute_data=0x7f3796811eb8) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:693
#10 0x0000000000aca7b8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7f3796811eb8) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#11 0x0000000000aca840 in zend_execute (op_array=0x7f3796841d80) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:388
#12 0x0000000000a862e6 in zend_execute_scripts (type=8, retval=0x0, file_count=3) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/Zend/zend.c:1341
#13 0x00000000009ead57 in php_execute_script (primary_file=0x7fff1ef4a8d0) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/main/main.c:2597
#14 0x0000000000b471c9 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff1ef4cc38) at /usr/src/php-5.6.11/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c:1964
```

All I see that there is some problem when calling mysqlnd function through PDO. But really nothing more. The code is running fine on older PHP versions ( < 5.6 ) s I don't assume it's problem of my code, rather some problem with PHP ?

PHP is compiled like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.6.11-fpm --enable-ftp --with-gd --enable-mbstring --enable-sockets --enable-zip --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/jpeg-9 --with-zlib --enable-embedded-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-png-dir=/usr/local/libpng --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/freetype --with-mcrypt=/usr/local/libmcrypt --with-mhash --enable-soap --enable-bcmath --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-mysql --enable-fpm --enable-debug
```

I will appreciate any hint or help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, finally (after few hours of detective work) I have found answer to my own question. I will post it, as it may help someone with the same problem.

Actually there were 2 problems in my case. The main problem causing this behaviour was MySQL disconnecting after 60 idle seconds of persistent connection. I have this setting on production server as there is many requests each second so 60 seconds is reasonable setting (in contrast of 8 hours set in my.cnf as default - wait_timeout = 28800).

However I have copied this to a development server, where a request is made once in a while. So the 60 seconds limit was hit. And my then compiled PHP resulted in SEGFAULT.

During my search I also found this [PHP manual page dealing with possible MySQL libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php) in PHP. So I have used recommended compile directives:

```
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysql=mysqlnd
```

And then the dropped Mysql connection stopped the SEGFAULT problem, it only resulted in correct Exception thrown by PDO.

Hope it helps someone in future.